# How to store the access code of Google Drive locally and use for a long time?

Tags: google-drive-api

Now I am using Google Drive API to upload and download file from / to my Google Drive.

For this purpose, I am using CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET provided by Google.

But the problem is, everytime I run the program, the program will give me an URL, then I need to open the URL to press Accept, then get a code to continue running the program. The code itself will expire, so I have to this task over and over.

Is there anyway to store this code locally, so the program can run without interact with user?

Thank you very much

Comment: store the refresh token returned by google and use that each time you login.

Comment: I tried like this, but it does not work. Next time the token expired already.

Comment: That is the access token, refresh token is used to get a new access token

Comment: Thank you very much. But to get new access token, I need interaction with users (user need to click Accept in the web browser to get new access token). Is there anyway to get the access token automatically?

Comment: No to get a new access token you need to send the refresh token to the authentication server and request a new access token. This does not require any interaction with the user.

Comment: Do you have sample code or tutorial about this? Thanks so much

Comment: That would depend upon which language you are doing this in.

Comment: Any language is okay, but Java is the best. Tks so much

Answer (score 0):

when request to exchange `authorization_code` to `access_token`, this response will contains like this following format:

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

`access_token`: use to request with Google API, an yes itself will expire 'expires_in' seconds

other while with refresh_token you can refresh to get new valid `access_token` by use a Google refresh token API

read more at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp -> **Using a refresh token**